# Is there always a purely real representative for a metrized solvable Lie group?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, solvable-groups, non-positive-curvature

Alekseevski proves for Heintze groups (a special class of solvable Lie groups) that any such group admits a (left-invariant) metric which is isometric to a purely real Heintze group (again equipped with some left-invariant metric).

Can the same be said for arbitrary solvable Lie groups? Here by purely real, I mean that the adjoint action has purely real eigenvalues when acting as an automorphism of the Lie algebra.

In case it is relevant, I am only interested in those solvable Lie groups which admit nonpositively curved (CAT(0)) metrics.

Comment: You need to assume the solvable Lie group to be simply connected. If so, yes, it follows from Lemma 2.4 in https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0703192. But probably follows from Gordon-Wilson work in the 80s.

Comment: Title of @YCor's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/381760/is-there-always-a-purely-real-representative-for-a-metrized-solvable-lie-group#comment970435_381760):  [de Cornulier - Dimension of asymptotic cones of Lie groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0703192).